# Wirite test using JestJs with React Context Provider and Hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am newbie to front-end development and working on authentication with Okta-React. I have multiple components where i would like to pass logged in user information so i using react context with hook. This works fine but i would like to have some simple test written but currently it just goes on endless loop.

```
  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88
    Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
        in AuthProvider (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useAuthContext } from '../AuthContext/AuthContext';
import AuthProvider from '../AuthProvider/AuthProvider';
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new adapter() });

jest.mock("@okta/okta-react", () => ({
    useOktaAuth: () => {
      return {
        authState: {},
        authService: {},
      };
    },
    withOktaAuth: (x: any) => x,
}));

describe('AuthContext', () => {
    it('user not logged - isAuth returns false', () => {

        const TestComponent = () => {
            const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthContext();

            return (
                <>
                    <div data-testId="value">{isAuthenticated?.toString()}</div>
                </>
            )
        }

        const wrapper = mount(
            <AuthProvider>
                <TestComponent />
            </AuthProvider>
        );

        expect(wrapper.find('[data-testId="value"]').text()).toEqual("false");
    });
});
```

AuthContext.tsx

```js
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { IAuthContext } from '../../types/IAuthContext';

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({
    user: null,
    isAuthenticated: null,
    accessToken: ''
});

export default AuthContext;
```

AuthProvider.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import AuthContext from '../../components/AuthContext/AuthContext';
import { IAuthContext } from '../../types/IAuthContext';
import { IUserInfo } from '../../types/IUserInfo';

const AuthProvider = (props: any) => {
    const { authState, authService } = useOktaAuth();
    const [authContext, setAuthContext] = useState<IAuthContext>(
        {} as IAuthContext
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
            setAuthContext({} as IAuthContext);
        } else {
            authService.getUser().then((info: IUserInfo) => {
                setAuthContext({
                    accessToken: authState.accessToken,
                    isAuthenticated: authState.isAuthenticated,
                    user: info
                });
            });
        }
    }, [authState, authService]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the portion of the error message that is relevant to your problem: `one of the dependencies changes on every render`.

When you mock the `useOktaAuth` hook, you tell `jest` to always return a new object.

```
// ...
useOktaAuth: () => { // this will always return a new object (on every render)
  return {
    authState: {},
    authService: {},
  };
}
// ...
```

So each render, when the hook is called, the return value of the hook will be different.

What happens next is:

1. your `useEffect` calling `setAuthContext({} as IAuthContext);` (because of your mock not having `isAuthenticated`)
2. this call triggering a re-render
3. this re-render generating new values for `authState` and `authService` (your mock)
4. these new values triggering your `useEffect`
5. your `useEffect` calling `setAuthContext({} as IAuthContext);`
6. this call triggering a re-render
7. this re-render generating new values for `authState` and `authService`
8. ... Do you see the loop ?

You have to make the return value of your mock hook "stable" (always return the same reference) in order for your test to work.

For example:

```
useOktaAuth: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ 
  authState: {},
  authService: {}
})
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked fine. I got another quick question how can i mock authService.getUser().


jest.mock('@okta/okta-react', () => ({
    useOktaAuth: jest.fn(),
    withOktaAuth: jest.fn((x) => x)
}));

Tried this mockreturn but getting `TypeError: authService.getUser(...).then is not a function`


        useOktaAuth.mockReturnValue({
            authState: { isAuthenticated: true },
            authService: {
                getUser: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => user)
            }
        });

Comment: Your mock `getUser` has to return a promise. Try `.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(user))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `useOktaAuth` was mocked incorrectly. It returns new state on each call while it's supposed to preserve state. This results in infinite `useEffect` calls because inputs don't prevent this.

It should be:

```
jest.mock("@okta/okta-react", () => ({
    useOktaAuth: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ 
      authState: {},
      authService: {}
    }),
    withOktaAuth: jest.fn(x => x)
}));
```

This won't make the test pass because it's synchronous while the component is not. The promise that `authService.getUser()` returns needs to be awaited in test before making the assertion.